# Convert hours-minutes-seconds duration in dataframe to minutes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I have a csv with a column that represents time durations of two discrete events.

```
Day,Duration
Mon,"S: 3h0s, P: 18m0s"
Tues,"S: 3h0s, P: 18m0s"
Wed,"S: 4h0s, P: 18m0s"
Thurs,"S: 30h, P: 10m0s"
Fri,"S: 15m, P: 3h0s"
```

I want to split that duration into two distinct columns and consistently represent the time in `minutes`. Right now, it is shown in `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds`, like `S: 3h0s, P: 18m0s`. So the output should look like this:

```
    Day             Duration   S(min) P(min)
0   Mon    S: 3h0s, P: 18m0s     180     18
1  Tues    S: 3h0s, P: 18m0s     180     18
2   Wed    S: 4h0s, P: 18m0s     240     18
3  Thur   S: 30h0s, P: 10m0s    1800     10
4   Fri      S: 15m, P: 3h0s      15    180
```

But when I do in `str.replace`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/file.csv")
df["S(min)"] = df['Duration'].str.split(',').str[0]
df["P(min)"] = df['Duration'].str.split(',').str[-1]

df['S(min)'] = df['S(min)'].str.replace("S: ", '').str.replace("h", '*60').str.replace('m','*1').str.replace('s','*(1/60)').apply(eval)
df['P(min)'] = df['P(min)'].str.replace("P: ", '').str.replace("h", '*60').str.replace('m','*1').str.replace('s','*(1/60)').apply(eval)
```

some of the calculations are off:

```
     Day           Duration  S(min)     P(min)
0    Mon  S: 3h0s, P: 18m0s    30.0   3.000000
1   Tues  S: 3h0s, P: 18m0s    30.0   3.000000
2    Wed  S: 4h0s, P: 18m0s    40.0   3.000000
3  Thurs   S: 30h, P: 10m0s  1800.0   1.666667
4    Fri    S: 15m, P: 3h0s    15.0  30.000000
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the csv data used to build the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex and [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html)

```py
df[['S', 'P']] = df['Duration'].str.extract(r'(S: .*?), P:( .*)')
df['S(min)'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration'].str.replace('[SP]: ', '', regex=True).str.split(',').str[0]).dt.total_seconds() / 60
df['P(min)'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration'].str.replace('[SP]: ', '', regex=True).str.split(',').str[-1]).dt.total_seconds() / 60

df.drop(['S', 'P'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

**More Simplified** approach with different regex pattern:

```py
df[['S', 'P']] = df['Duration'].str.extract(r'S: (.*?), P: (.*)')
df['S'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['S']).dt.total_seconds()/60
df['P'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['P']).dt.total_seconds()/60

df = df.rename(columns = {'S': 'S(min)', 'P': 'P(min)'})
print(df)
```

---

```
    Day            Duration  S(min)  P(min)
0   Mon   S: 3h0s, P: 18m0s   180.0    18.0
1  Tues   S: 3h0s, P: 18m0s   180.0    18.0
2   Wed   S: 4h0s, P: 18m0s   240.0    18.0
3  Thur  S: 30h0s, P: 10m0s  1800.0    10.0
4   Fri     S: 15m, P: 3h0s    15.0   180.0
```

Comment: `.str.replace("S: ", '').str.replace("P: ", '')` can be replaced by `.str.replace('[SP]: ', '', regex=True)`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
df.assign(
    **df['Duration'].str.split(':|,', expand=True)[[1,3]]
    .apply(pd.to_timedelta)
    .apply(lambda x: x.dt.total_seconds().div(60))
    .rename({1: 'S(min)', 3: 'P(min)'}, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
    Day            Duration  S(min)  P(min)
0   Mon   S: 3h0s, P: 18m0s   180.0    18.0
1  Tues   S: 3h0s, P: 18m0s   180.0    18.0
2   Wed   S: 4h0s, P: 18m0s   240.0    18.0
3  Thur  S: 30h0s, P: 10m0s  1800.0    10.0
4   Fri     S: 15m, P: 3h0s    15.0   180.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot '+' in '*60' and '*1' but this does not solve the problem if hour or minute are missing. You can also use a more complex [regex](https://regex101.com/r/m7ltMI/1) to explode all values in different columns:

```
S_pat = r'S:\s*(?:(?P<S_h>\d+)(?=h)h)?\s*(?:(?P<S_m>\d+)(?=m)m)?\s*(?:(?P<S_s>\d+)(?=s)s)?'
P_pat = r'P:\s*(?:(?P<P_h>\d+)(?=h)h)?\s*(?:(?P<P_m>\d+)(?=m)m)?\s*(?:(?P<P_s>\d+)(?=s)s)?'

duration = df['Duration'].str.extract(SP_pat).fillna(0).astype(int)
duration = (duration.mul([60, 1, 1/60, 60, 1, 1/60])
                    .groupby(duration.columns.str[0], axis=1)
                    .sum().add_suffix('(min)'))

out = pd.concat([df, duration], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    Day            Duration  P(min)  S(min)
0   Mon   S: 3h0s, P: 18m0s    18.0   180.0
1  Tues   S: 3h0s, P: 18m0s    18.0   180.0
2   Wed   S: 4h0s, P: 18m0s    18.0   240.0
3  Thur  S: 30h0s, P: 10m0s    10.0  1800.0
4   Fri     S: 15m, P: 3h0s   180.0    15.0

# duration after extraction, before computing
>>> duration
  S_h S_m S_s P_h P_m P_s
0   3   0   0   0  18   0
1   3   0   0   0  18   0
2   4   0   0   0  18   0
3  30   0   0   0  10   0
4   0  15   0   3   0   0
```